# Datos del día actual y de 7 días atrás

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Estoy trabajando en un reporte el cual se hace cada martes, hoy siendo martes se debe de generar uno, donde solo aparecerán si su `quantity(cantidad actual)` es menor a su `reorder_level (cantidad minima)`.

Como dije se genera cada martes, entonces necesito que tome la fecha de hoy hasta el día 27 de noviembre son `7` días de diferencia y solo mande los que cumplan esa condición.

Mi problema es que haciendo pruebas con días mayores a los 7 días de diferencia me sigue mostrando esa información. Cuando es errónea.

**Ejemplo:** Tengo una `description_item` de `28/08/2018` y tengo `2` mas que están dentro del rango de martes a martes. Cuando ejecuto mi `query` me trae también el de agosto y no debería de ser así.

La fecha la debe de tomar del sistema, no debería porque escribirla, e independientemente si sea martes o no si se quiere generar el reporte, tomara el día actual menos 7 días.

Este es mi query:

```
select description_item,quantity,reorder_Level 
from inventory_list 
where  quantity < reorder_Level 
and  date_add(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
```

Comment: no estas comparando a nada con esta funcion date_add(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY).. no falta un > a no se.. una fecha?

Comment: no será: `and  (campo_fecha>NOW() AND campo_fecha<date_add(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY))`

Comment: @Fly asi vas a traer todo lo que NO esta dentro de los ultimos 7 dias.. seria eso, pero negado ;)

Comment: A que te refieres con `campo_fecha`?.....Yo requiero la fecha actual menos 7 días, o me estoy confundiendo tal vez, si pudieras explicarme.

Comment: Puse campo_fecha porque no sabia como se llama el campo que usas, los demás están en ingles y no quería poner `date`.  @gbianchi tienes toda la razón, confundí los términos, seria `and (campo_fecha<NOW() AND campo_fecha>date_add(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY))`

Answer (score 4):

Solo te falta comparar la fecha que generas con el DATE_ADD

La consulta quedaría así:

```
select description_item,quantity,reorder_Level 
from inventory_list 
where  quantity < reorder_Level 
and fecha <= NOW() AND fecha >= date_add(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
```

Claro esto es suponiendo que tu columna en la que tienes la fecha del item se llame fecha.

Aunque también puedes usar la condición BETWEEN que puedes utilizar para verificar valores dentro de rangos (no solo fechas). quedaría así

```
select description_item,quantity,reorder_Level 
from inventory_list 
where  quantity < reorder_Level 
and fecha BETWEEN date_add(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY) AND NOW()
```

Comment: Entiendo lo que quieres hacer, pero tal vez yo no lo entiendo de esa manera.. si tengo una columna que se llama RegisterDate que es la fecha en que se registro el item, pero independientemente y no creo que deberia de ponerlo, ya que yo requiero que tome la fecha del sistema y restandole los 7 dias me muestre todos los que cumplan con la condicion, no logro entender porque debo de escribir una fecha, para comparar.

Comment: Deseas que tu query retorne todos los items que se hayan creado en esos últimos 7 días y que cumplan con tu condición `quantity < reorder_level` ?

Comment: Exactamente! :o

Comment: bueno por eso debes usar la fecha en que se crearon los registros. la expresión `date_add(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)` solo te retorna una fecha es el dia de hoy - 7 dias. entonces si solo usas la expresión no estas comparando nada. le estas diciendo a mysql `where quantity < reoreder_level' and 'xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx'` que al tener un valor es como si le dijeras `where condición and TRUE`  (por que now() siempre te dará un valor) entonces solo evalúas la condición y el resto de la expresión siempre sera verdadera para cualquier registro.

Comment: @VirusDetected dices: " yo requiero que tome la fecha del sistema y restandole los 7 dias me muestre todos los que cumplan con la condicion" ¿cual es la condición? sólo estas poniendo una fecha.